# Oracle SQL create table with character set

Tags: sql, oracle

trying to run a create table statement with character set defined

not sure how to format the statement, seems like that might be the issue

first attempt:

```
CREATE TABLE blocking_map (ID INTEGER,  (BLOCK_KEY VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci))

Error report -
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

second attempt:

```
CREATE TABLE blocking_map (ID INTEGER, BLOCK_KEY VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)

Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL? The question is tagged as Oracle, but the syntax you're using implies MySQL.

Comment: Where [in the Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/index.html) did you find that syntax?

Comment: okay, I guess I need to convert it to Oracle SQL then, but don't know how. I was looking at this site https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.1-en/charset-column.html

Comment: Oracle does not allow changing the character set of tables. Tables must use the system characterset. If your database is stuck in an old characterset like ASCII7, you can create NVARCHAR2 columns that will use the national characterset (typically UTF16). But it might help to explain exactly what problem you're trying to solve.